# normalizing the plot using mean value

Tags: matlab, plot

This is how i am plotting my graph. Now i want to normalize the y axis by dividing it by mean value and after multipyling it by 100. here in the plot i am already getting the standarde deviation value. How to get the mean value and normalize it.[image]

```
len = [10, 100, 1000, 2000, 3500, 5000];

for k1 = 1:length(len)
    standard_deviation(k1) = std(resdamp(1:len(k1), 500));
end

len_interp = linspace(min(len), max(len));
stdev11_interp = interp1(len, standard_deviation, len_interp,'spline');
figure(5),plot(len_interp, stdev11_interp); xlabel('measurements'); ylabel('standarddev');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do

```
plot(len_interp, stdev11_interp/mean(stdev11_interp)*100);
```

Comment: In the answer, you are multiplying 100 with mean value only right? I should be multipling with (y axis/mean)*100.

Comment: How do you mean? it's the same thing, no?

Comment: sorry,  it 's same thing. Thanks :)

Comment: I have one question, since I am multiplying y/mean with 100. Now I have converted y axis into percentage right?

Comment: you've converted it into percentage of your mean, so your mean is 100%. If you would like your max to be 100% simply divide by max(stdev...) instead of mean(stdev...).

Comment: ahh ok. Thanks for info @ Ihcgeneva.